# Loading controllers from different folder in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, I can use `$autoload['packages']` to specify additional locations for libraries, models, and helpers. But how do I specify additional locations for controllers.

What I want is this: If a URL specifies controller `xyzzy`, CodeIgniter should first look for the usual `application/controllers/Ctrl_xyzzy.php` file, and if it doesn't find it, it should look for `other_place/controllers/Ctrl_xyzzy.php` instead.

Is that possible?

Comment: For this you can use HMVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calling a controller from another controller you need to use HMVC

refer this link
https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc